Using Power Automate to refresh Stock Level data with Bloomberg
I have a 'master' file with 500 stocks/tickers and around 100 data points for each ticker that I need to pull. I've been running into the issue where the file often gets stuck, crashes, or just takes a long time to update when I refresh.
Is power automate a valid option so that I could update the file automatically, at say 4am and 12pm every weekday? The issue is I have other files that pulls data from this 'master', so ideally I would want to try to not have to open this 'master' file, and it would automatically refresh twice a day at the specified times.
The other files that are pulling from the 'master' file are using index matches, so they would hopefully update automatically for the updated 'master' file if I open them and refresh them.
I am using the website version of PowerAutomate, where I go to make.powerautomate.com and can view the flow and run it.

The short answer is yes. There are also numerous other options, but additional context is needed to give any futher guidance. Good luck.

Thanks for the answer, could you tell me what other context you need? I'm reading that using refreshAllDataConnections doesn't refresh the cells if they aren't from Power BI or using Power Query. The other option seems to be PowerShell scripts?

Context directly related to your question would be are you using the web/cloud or desktop version of Power Automate and what is the current way you are getting your data and are you willing to change? More generic context include what skill and knowledge of automation you currently possess and how far down the rabbit hole are you willing to go regardless of what path you choose? For instance, you could do everything in VBA and then use windows task scheduler for the timing.

Thanks for the reply. I haven't used PowerAutomate before and have only done a little bit of VBA code, but I am fluent in Python and SQL, so I'm hoping I could pick up the necessary syntax for VBA or PowerShell or anything else.

If I had python knowledge, I would use that to create a python executable that gets your data and saves it to your excel master file. Then I would just use Windows Task Scheduler for the timing. My personal experience is that  these RPA's are still to simplistic to perform the complicated tasks that I think up, without getting into additional programming. But these solutions are improving.

So the issue is that the data is available through excel add-in only. I can't use the API because it's too expensive, which is why I thought PowerAutomate or PowerShell script might be the way to do it.

to me via "excel add-in" would almost rule out powershell. You mentioned using web version of power automate, I don't know if the power automate interface can mimic a button click (or whatever action is needed) to get your bloomberg data. Finally, I will assume your excel file is stored in oneDrive, which means office script (VBA is for desktop excel files). I'm not sure I can offer anymore guidance.

Thank you @gns100. So the workbook.refreshAll() in powershell wouldn't refresh the data link? The bloomberg add-in is basically an equation in a cell that will pull from bloomberg's server. I just need to find a way to basically select all and refresh all, or hit 'F9' essentially. The file is stored in oneDrive, so does that mean I could use an office script to try to do this?

I did a search of: "power automate refresh excel data connection" and it seems like this can be accomplished. I suggest at this point you decide on a path and come up with an action plan to test if this can work in your workflow. Perhaps Power Automate is the lowest cost of entry. Anyway, continued discussion with me is pure speculation at this point. If you do come up with a suitable solution I sugges you post it as an answer (redacting where needed) for others to see what you accomplished.

This website is for solving specific problems you encounter with software, not for "Can I do X with software?". For that there's research based on documentation. Or you could ask for software recoomendation on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com
